# How to remove unity 2d workspace animation?

Tags: workspaces, unity-2d

Unity 2d's workspace animation runs very slowly on my old graphics card. How do you disable them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `transitionDuration = 0` in the file `/usr/share/unity-2d/spreed/utils.js`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple way to disable the workspace switcher. It requires changes in the code of Unity 2D.

Comment: And for the hard ways, see Igor's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Ubuntu Precise, and the following did it for me:

- Run "CompizConfig Settings Manager" (not sure if it's installed by default)
- Select "Desktop Wall" under Desktop
- Disable "Show Viewport Switcher Preview"
- Select the "Viewport Switching" tab
- Set "Wall Sliding Duration" to zero

Now when switching desktops via the keyboard, I don't get any animations.

Comment: The question is about Unity-2d, Compiz settings does not change Unity-2d behaviour.

Comment: Maybe this did not solve the original question, but it surely solved mine, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install [dconf-tools [image: Install dconf-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) (should be available in Maverick, it definitely is in Natty. I'm on Lucid so I can't check). Open `dconf-editor` and search for unity. There are several tunables, though I'm not sure the workspace animation is one of them.

Comment: ... no such option ...

Answer (score -2):

Probably the best solution is to log in with the "Classic Gnome Desktop" (drop-down menu is at the bottom of the GDM Greeter after selecting your username). This will avoid Unity completely.

Comment: "Classic gnome desktop" keeps crashing. And anyway, unity 2d is much fancier.